Why Does this Failed Import Cause Future Imports to Also Fail (which otherwise wouldn't)?
This question is really just about the "why." I'm not actually interested in a work-around. I just want to understand why this doesn't work as is.
IMPORTANT EDIT: apparently the issue described next is specific to my PC. The question becomes, what might cause the issue.
Basically, I have a tiny python repo https://github.com/ThomasLastName/bnns in which I have a script with a try/except block:
# pseudo-code of demo.py (DOES NOT WORK)
try:
    from dir.file import func
except:     # behavior doe NOT seem to change if you instead say `except ModuleNotFoundError:`
    append_the_root_directory_of_this_repo_to_the_path()
    from dir.file import func

which triggers a ModuleNotFoundError. The full error output on my machine is
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\thoma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\bnns\scripts\demo.py", line 4, in <module>
    from bnns.SSGE import func
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bnns.SSGE'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\thoma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\bnns\scripts\demo.py", line 19, in <module>
    from bnns.SSGE import func
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bnns.SSGE'

What I want to understand is: why does the following work?
# pseudo-code of fixed_demo.py (DOES WORK)
try:
    1/0 
except:
    append_the_root_directory_of_this_repo_to_the_path()
    from dir.file import func

Unfortunately, an isolated code snippet does not contain enough context to be reproducible, because the file organization matters. Therefore, I've made a github repo: https://github.com/ThomasLastName/bnns that I'm afraid you'll need to clone in order to reproduce my results. I hope that is acceptable... Also, I'm sorry to say that I have no real background in computer science, so I'm afraid I won't be able to understand overly technical answers... Thank you, I would really appreciate some help in understanding this.

Does it work if you change to except ModuleNotFoundError:?

I think I tried that and the behavior persists. But hold on let me try again real quick

Indeed the the same error persists

Which line is raising the error, the one in the try block or the one in the except block?

In the except block.

Put that in the question so you can preserve the formatting.

absolutely. I'll do that right now

I was able to get someone else to test it.... and I think it my be simply an issue with my PC...

I suspect the problem is with the code that's adding to sys.path. It doesn't seem to do anything related to the path of the repo, it starts from os.getcwd().

Is there a better directory to start from?

Apparently, the problem is with the code in the except block that adds the path to sys.path. Maybe the file doesn't exists at all?

@ThomasWinckelman The directory containing the script, since the directory you want to add is a sibling.
